# Экранирование скобок в XSLT

Tags: xslt

XSLT шаблонизатор интерпретирует все что находится между фигурными скобками {}

А я использую knockout.js, который юзает {} для биндингов.

Вопрос: как сказать XSLT чтобы он выводил эти скобки как есть, а не пытался интерпретировать?

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался, надо пользовать xsl:attribute, там скобки не компилируются